# How to pass store data in a remote process say alarm reciever and retrive it in some activty

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, alarmmanager

I want to save the number of notifications the receiver receives.
I am using shared preferences but it does not give me the correct results. 
Neither MODE_MULTI_PROCESS nor MODE_PRIVATE.

What is a good way to store the number of received notifications so that the number of unread notifications and read notifications can be calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my point of view best way to deal with Notifications count is Shared preferences.
In most of cases it works and i have used it many times. What you can do is that whenever you receive notification Increment count of Shared Preference and store it in Preference.
May be you forget something to put in your code. If possible put your code snippet.